# Compose: how to rework View + drawable selector into Composable element

Tags: android, composable

I have clickable Android View (custom button), that after clicking changes background, and animates color from *pressed* state to *normal* state.

The drawable resource is defined like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="1000">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00f"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Note that only *exit* fade duration is set, so that after press, the color is immediately changed to pressed, and after release, it fades from blue to transparent in 1000ms.

Now I try to rework that into composable:

```
@Composable
fun But() {
    val its = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    var pressed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var animT by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var bg by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Transparent) }

    LaunchedEffect(its) {
        its.interactions.collect { i->
            when(i) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    App.log("P")
                    animT = 0
                    pressed = true
                }

                is PressInteraction.Cancel,
                is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                    App.log("R")
                    animT = 1000
                    pressed = false

                }
            }
            bg = if(pressed) Color.Blue else Color.Transparent
        }
    }
    App.log("pressed: $pressed")
    val bg1 by animateColorAsState(bg, TweenSpec(animT))
    Box(
        Modifier
            .background(bg1)
            .clickable(interactionSource = its, indication = null,
                onClick = {
                })
            .size(50.dp),

    ) {
    }
}
```

I collect user interaction, and successfully catch and log *press* and *release* state, and changing color and animation time by these events.
In general, it works, but it fails in fast press/release sequences, because the interaction events both execute, but entire item is recomposed only after both of the events are run, so the element doesn't notice fast press, and doesn't animate from blue to transparent.

Log output:

```
11:31:30.081  I  P
11:31:30.081  I  R
11:31:30.090  I  pressed: false
```

Please advice how to implement this so that it reliably works and animates the color.